# SQLite Python массовое добавление INSERT INTO

Tags: python, sqlite

Я новичок в SQL. Есть директория с 6к текстовыми файлами, 18Гб. Я написал скрипт для добавления их всех в базу. Одна таблица, одна колонка, но она с параметром `UNIQUE`, дабы исключить дубли строк.
Вроде бы всё работает как надо, НО происходит это ОЧЕНЬ медленно. Я уже и журнал отключил. Как можно ускорить процесс? Может ли мне помочь `BEGIN TRANSACTION`? Я не совсем понимаю как это работает. Если да, то накидайте небольшой пример.

```
import sqlite3
import os, glob
x = 0
con =  sqlite3.connect('baza.db')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS combo_baza (combo TEXT UNIQUE)')
con.execute('''PRAGMA journal_mode = OFF''')

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('E:\\Base\\files\\'):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".txt"):
             file_path = str((os.path.join(root, file))).replace('\\', '/')
             print(file_path)
             x += 1
             print(x)
        combo_file = open(file_path, encoding='utf-8')
        try:
            combo_file_first_stroke = combo_file.readline()
        except:
            print("Error")
        if "@" and ":" in combo_file_first_stroke:
            try:
                combo_stroke = combo_file.readlines()
            except:
                print("Error")
            for i in combo_stroke:
                combo_str = [(i)]
                try:
                    cur.execute("""INSERT INTO combo_baza (combo) VALUES (?);
                        """, combo_str)
                except sqlite3.IntegrityError:
                    pass
            con.commit()
            combo_file.close()
        print("OK")
```

Comment: Попробуйте `cur.executemany`

Comment: Сколько строк в файлах? Какая средняя длина строки? Как часто строки дублируются? Сколько оперативной памяти доступно?

Comment: Строк в файлах 100-500к, средняя длина 40, дубли редко, оперативная память - обычный ноут 8Гб. 
За час выходит примерно + 700Мб к базе. Я новичок в SQL, может это нормальная скорость? Но я так понимаю что из за параметра `UNIQUE` с ростом базы скорость добавления будет ещё уменьшаться?

Comment: UNIQUE требует чтобы индекс в базе обновлялся после добавления каждой записи. Да, замедляет.

Comment: Сейчас попробовал без `UNIQUE` , скорость взлетела в разы. Может в моём случае проще и быстрее сначала залить все строки в базу, а потом уже из готовой базы удалить все дубли?

Comment: Боюсь дубли удалять будет не просто.

Comment: Думаю, самый эффективный метод такой:   строим в памяти set, в который складываем хешит всех читаемых с диска строк. Если при чтении с диска хеш строки есть в сете в памяти - то даже не пытаемся вставлять строку в базу. Использование хеша нужно, чтобы объем считанной с диска инфы не превысил объем используемой программой памяти. Иначе можно было бы хранить в памяти set самих строк.

Comment: Оператор `if "@" and ":" in combo_file_first_stroke:` работает не так как вы ожидаете.

Comment: @S.H., есть проблема: один хеш занимает около 38 байт в памяти. Для 6*10^8 строк потребуется 23Gb памяти.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy - А если использовать md5 - хеш? Он вроде занимает только 16 байт. ТОгда для хешей понадобитмя меньше 10 гб памяти, причем, если дубликаты есть - еще меньше, а это уже близко к указанному размеру оперативки в ноуте. Возможно, можно найти еще более короткие хеши?

Comment: `hash` в Python - восемь байт. Остальные 30 байт - накладные расходы на хранение значения в памяти.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy - Спасибо, не знал. Хм. Как неэкономно то! ну, если не докупать памяти - только сделать свой способ хранения :-) Но это будет очень низкоуровневый с точки зрения питона код... Теоретически, можно просто аллоцировать кусок памяти и начать его заполнять полученными хешами, засовывая их примерно в то место, куда они могут попасть благодаря своему "значению" (т. е. хеши, начинающиеся на 00 00 00- ближе к началу, на FF FF FF - ближе к концу, и поддерживая упорядоченность)

Comment: numpy поддерживает упакованные битовые массивы. Если хеш поместить в диапазон [0...2^35), то он будет представлен одним битом в массиве на один гигабайт.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy - хорошая мысль! но тут уже есть риск коллизии, и в случае коллизии алгоритм вообще не будет вставлять данные в таблицу. Жалко данные... Хм. Даже не знаю, что еще придумать!

Comment: Число коллизий надо оценить. Если их не много, то найденные строки выделяются в отдельное множество и обрабатываются в памяти. Итого три прохода: 1. накапливаем хеши с коллизиями. 2. строки без коллизий помещаем в базу. 3. строки с коллизиями чистим и затем помещаем в базу.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy - а как детектировать коллизию хеша? Ведь она выглядит так: при чтении очередной строки я считаю её хеш, и оказывается, что такой хеш у меня в структуре, хранящейся в памяти, уже есть. Но при этом это может быть хеш другой строки. А метода - как узнать это - я не знаю.

Comment: Это и не нужно. Бит 100 на первом проходе показал коллизию. ОК. На втором проходе все строки с этим битом отложим в отдельное множество.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy - спасибо за объяснения и ценные идеи, всё таки я не совсем понял алгоритм, который позвояляет "безболезненно" работать с коллизиями... Может, напишете ответ? там можно было бы всё расскзать. Но яне настаиваю, просто мысль...

Comment: Попробую. Но это целое исследование.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy редко в некоторых файлах бывает мусор и то что мне добавлять в базу не нужно.
`if "@" and ":" in combo_file_first_stroke:` - если в первой строке файла нет указанных символов, то пропустить файл и продолжать цикл, не перебирая каждую строку в файле.

Comment: Этот код не проверяет что `@` есть в первой строчке. Расставляя скобки: `if ("@") and (":" in combo_file_first_stroke):`. Первый множитель приводится к `True`. Получаем `if ":" in combo_file_first_stroke:`.

Answer (score 0):

В одном из своих парсеров я писал что-то похожее, у данного метода есть ограничение на кол-во строк, которые вы добавляете.

Далее пример формирования самого запроса:

```
>>> rows_list = [f'({row_data})' for row_data in [1,2,3]]
>>> query_data = ','.join(rows_list)
>>> query = f'INSERT INTO combo_baza (combo) VALUES {query_data};'
>>> print(query)

INSERT INTO combo_baza (combo) VALUES (1),(2),(3);
```

Формируете запрос и выполняете его.

Ссылка на оф. документацию: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html

Ссылка на пример из интернета: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-insert/